# Use search with regex to find Korean characters using Python

Tags: python, regex, windows

Using Python 2.7.9 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit

I'm using the following code to search for any Korean characters ( http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.3.html )

`line = ['x'. 'y', 'z', '쭌', 'a']`

```
if any([re.search("[%s-%s]" % ("\xE3\x84\xB1".decode('utf-8'), "\xEC\xAD\x8C".decode('utf-8')), x) for x in line[3:]]):
    print "found character"
```

When ever I run the script and give it the following character `쭌` the console shows `∞¡î` which is a result of IDLE / Command Prompt being unable to show Korean characters I'm guessing.

`쭌` is the last character that I was hoping to match in the regex

So is the above search correct at least? I'd prefer to know I at least have the right pattern to search for and spend time trying to make the console show the proper Korean characters.

I've tried in command prompt to do `cph 1252` and nothing. It never prints out "found character" so I wouldn't ever know.

If it helps, the script is receiving text from an IRC channel where Korean is usually spoken.

Comment: Please create the shortest, *complete* program that demonstrates the error you are having.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Added a line for ya...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Unicode strings (note the "u" prefixes):

```
import re

line = [u'x', u'y', u'z', u'쭌', u'a']

if any([re.search(u'[\u3131-\ucb4c]', x) for x in line[3:]]):
    print "found character"
```

Comment: The regex pattern matches some Cherokee, Cyrillic, Devanagari, Ethiopic, Latin, and Myanmar. It also matches Yijing Hexagram Symbols, non_Hangul characters, Yi, Lisu, Vai, Bamum, Syloti Nagri, Phags-pa, Saurashtra, Kayah Li, Rejang, Javanese, Cham, Tai Viet, Meetei Mayek characters. It also fails to capture all Hangul.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library (not to be confused with re), you could do this:

```
import regex
regex.search(r'\p{IsHangul}', '오소리')
```

or in a function to detect at least one Hangul character:

```py
import regex

def is_hangul(value):
    if regex.search(r'\p{IsHangul}', value):
        return True
    return False

print(is_hangul('오소리'))      # True
print(is_hangul('mushroom'))   # False
print(is_hangul('뱀'))         # True
```